# Know a pixel is transparent

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I know how to get each pixel from a image and its RGBA value. My question is how to determine a pixel is transparent or not. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if alpha part of rgba value is equal to 0, if it is that means the pixel is fully transparent. ANd if it's equal to 255 isn't transparent at all.